# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated with URL Trigger

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm not too sure if this was already answered cause I tried looking through all the links.

I am trying to dismiss a `UIViewController` that contains a `UIWebView` that will be used for a login page. The WebView loads the login page and I have set the view to dismiss when the title is exactly what the Title to the webpage is when the user has successfully logged in. the dismiss never happens.

So... `LoginWebView` Loads > Users enters login credentials > User Logs in Sucessfully > WebPage Title Triggers Current View to dismissModal and `UITabBarController` Appears.

Buttons used with `IBAction` but what do I use for `UIWebView` with Conditional statements to work with dismissal of `LoginWebView`?

I hope I have elaborated enough

Comment: What is exactly the problem? The view controller is not dismissed when the title changes?

Comment: Yes When the default page after login appears. It doesn't dismiss

Comment: When, where and how do you check the title?

Comment: Unsure if I had implemented it correctly but I had used `NSString *pageTitle = [self.loginPage stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];` then created the if statement. I had put this in `-(IBAction)` at first realizing I'm unable to use it because I'm not using it with a button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the title of the loaded page in `UIWebView`. You need to call some java script to get the title:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *theTitle= [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];

    if([theTitle isEqualToString:@"yourString"])
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Note that if you are showing the controller with web view not modally but pushing it on the navigation stack, you should dismiss the view controller by calling:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: it still have not dismissed but i'm not doubting the code in this answer but how I have implemented the view is incorrect. Should I not have the `LoginWebView` be the Initial View Controller. Also it isn't stacked in a navigation controller.

Comment: If the `LoginWebView ` is the initial view controller then it will not be dismissed because there is no other view controller to dismiss to. You have to change it, so the `LoginWebView` is not the initial VC if you want to dismiss it.

Comment: ohh forgot to mention that it segues to `UITabBarController`. or i'm just assuming that I had implemented it correctly but may not be so.